# Verwendung von Präposition in diesem Satz

Tags: preposition

Könnte dieser Satz mit einer anderen Präposition beginnen? Könnte dieser Satz beispielsweise mit "mit" beginnen?

> Zu den typischen Symptomen der Krankheit gehören hohes Fieber, geschwollene Lymphknoten und Windpocken-ähnliche Pusteln.
> <sub>*Quelle: [welt.de](https://www.welt.de/eilmeldung/article240084603/WHO-erklaert-Affenpocken-Ausbruch-zu-einer-internationalen-Notlage.html)*</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In dem Beispiel gehört die Präposition „zu“ zu dem [Verb „gehören“](https://www.dwds.de/wb/geh%C3%B6ren). Sie kann daher nicht einfach durch eine andere ersetzt werden.

Answer (score 1):

#### Nein.

Der Teil *»zu den typischen Symptomen der Krankheit«* ist ein Präpositionalobjekt, das vom Verb des Satzes (also von *»gehören«*) regiert wird.

Präpositionalobjekt sehen adverbialen Ergänzungen zum Verwechseln ähnlich, weil sie ebenfalls mit einer Präposition beginnen und ein inneres Objekt haben, dessen Fall von dieser einleitenden Präposition bestimmt ist. Aber adverbialen Ergänzungen sind optional und beliebig austauschbar, und es kann beliebig viele davon in einem Satz geben. Das Hinzufügen oder Entfernen einer adverbialen Ergänzung verändert zwar die Aussage eines Satzes, aber es verändert nicht, ob der Satz grammatikalisch richtig oder falsch ist.

- Beispiele für adverbiale Bestimmungen:
  Jede einzelne adverbiale Bestimmung ist hier zur Veranschaulichung von einem Klammerpaar umgeben. Diese Klammern sollen nur den Beginn und das Ende der jeweiligen adverbiale Bestimmung anzeigen. In einem normalen Text gibt es diese Klammern nicht.

  > Kurt trinkt (*zu dem Fisch*) (*bei jedem Wetter*) (*an jedem Freitag*) (*mit großem Vergnügen*) (*durch einen Strohhalm*) Wasser.

  Jede einzelne dieser adverbiale Bestimmungen kann man weglassen, und man kann auch weitere hinzufügen. Dabei kann jede beliebige Präposition vorkommen.

Präpositionalobjekte sind hingegen Objekte, das heißt, sie hängen vom Verb ab. Das ist so ähnlich wie mit jenen Objekten, die in einem bestimmten Fall stehen müssen. Da bestimmt das Verb den Fall des Objekts. Bei Präpositionalobjekten bestimmt das Verb die Präposition.

Es gibt Verben, die zwingend verlangen, dass ein Präpositionalobjekt vorhanden ist:

> falsch: <del>Walter kümmert sich.</del>
> richtig: Walter kümmert sich **um die Getränke.**

Häufiger kommt es aber vor, dass das Präpositionalobjekt optional ist. Wenn es aber vorhanden ist, muss es mit eienr bestimmten Präposition beginnen:

> Lisa wartet.
> Lisa wartet **auf ihren Freund.**

---

Das Verb *»gehören«* gehört zu einer dritten Gruppe: Es kann nicht ohne Objekt existieren, aber das Objekt kann entweder ein Präpositionalobjekt oder ein Kasusobjekt (in diesem Fall ein Dativobjekt) sein:

- mit Dativobjekt (*jemandem* gehören)

  > Der Hut gehört **der blonden Dame.**
- mit Präpositionalobjekt (*zu etwas* gehören)

  > Der Hut gehört **zu dem Kleid.**

Wenn es das Präpositionalobjekt sein soll, dann verlangt das Verb *»gehören«,* dass die Präposition *»zu«* ist.